# What's the difference between " classic"and "classical"?

Tags: meaning, differences, comparisons, ic-ical

I have run into quite a few occasions when I confused " classic" and " classical".

Answer (score 0):

Use ***classical*** to talk about the **culture** of the past, and **art** forms belonging to a long formal tradition:

1. I like classical music.
2. She’s only eight years old and she has learned to dance both classical and modern ballet.
3. He is one of our greatest classical actors.

Use ***classic*** to describe something **high-quality**. Note that we use it to mean something that is valued because it has a traditional style:

1. She was wearing a classic dark blue skirt.
2. It’s a classic motorbike from the 1940s.

A ***classic example*** is a **perfect example** of something (remember is as a common collocation):

1. The drug problem is a classic example of a global challenge.

Comment: How about historical and historic?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen "Historic" means important or likely to be important in history (historic moment/vote/meeting), while "historical" means related to the study of things from the past, related to history as a science (historical novel/document).

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer has got it fully clarified.On a side note,is there anything I could turn to once for all given I run into two or more confusing words now and then?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! If you see something confusing, please post it here. The explanation above should work. But it's possible that something might confuse you anyway. If it happens, consult a good dictionary and if it doesn't help, post your question here. I'll be happy to help!